# How to make binocular effect in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I need to make binocular effect with blur and scale inside custom frame to follow an object(sprite), like this

[image]

Any ideas how to make it?
Great thanks for help!

Comment: what about using CCLens3D ??

Answer (score 0):

Clip the area where you want to zoom to path (like the binocular edges) and then increase the scale (that's how i would do it in pure objective c).

If you're using cocos2d 2.0 it should work as the CCDirector is a UIViewController , in other versions, i don't know. Maybe try to do the same but you'll need some work-arounds